# How to display Images in a wxListCtrl (multicolumn report style)

Tags: image, icons, wxwidgets

I already managed to create wxListCtrls with either icons or multicolumn text like this

[Picture of two wxListCtrls](http://benezan-electronics.de/forum/pictures/toollist1.png)

Now I'd like to add an icon to each line of the text list on the left. I thought this should be possible as typical wxWidgets applications like code::blocks and wxSmith often diplay icons in list/tree views (resource browser window) and even in tabs of notebooks (compiler log window).
So how can I create something like this? (Everybody knows Windows Explorer)

[Picture of Explorer Window with icons](http://benezan-electronics.de/forum/pictures/explorer-icons.png)

I tried this...

```
SetImageList (ToolImages, wxIMAGE_LIST_NORMAL);
InsertColumn (0, "Icon");
SetColumnWidth (0, 40);
...
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    InsertItem (i, i);
    SetItemColumnImage (i, 0, i);
    SetItem (i, 1, IntToStr (i+1));
...
```

But as you can see, only the text gets displayd, the image column is blank. Is it possible at all to mix text and images in report mode? If not, what other wxControl class can I use to get the desired result?

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, and the [listctrl sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/v3.1.4/samples/listctrl/listtest.cpp) shows how to do it, in particular see `MyFrame::InitWithReportItems()` function. The only difference with your code seems to be that you use a different `InsertItem()` overload, so perhaps you should use `InsertItem(i, "")` instead.

Also check that your image list does have the 5 icons in it.

More generally, trying to reduce the differences between your code and the (working) sample will almost always quickly find the problem.

Comment: The sample you mentioned is gone. Do you have another tutorial for me?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, VZ, but I found out that it's not the InsertItem() but the SetImageList(). My image list was correct, but the "which" parameter wasn't. Replacing wxIMAGE_LIST_NORMAL by wxIMAGE_LIST_SMALL fixes the problem! I thought "SMALL" was only meant for the SMALL_ICON mode and that "NORMAL" should be the default. But yes, that makes sense, normal icons are big and don't fit in the text display. Would be nice if the documentation had told us that before long trial and error...

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example for  *SMALL ICONIC VIEW USING WXLISTCTRL* .Please place this code inside the class declaration.I did it in Frame based Windows Application using **CODE BLOCKS**.It will be useful to you.

`wxImageList *il=new wxImageList(32,32,false,0);`

`wxImageList *i2=new wxImageList(32,32,false,0);`

```
 wxDir dir(wxGetCwd());
wxDir dir1(wxGetCwd());



    if ( !dir.IsOpened() )

    {

        // deal with the error here - wxDir would already log an error message
        // explaining the exact reason of the failure
        return;
    }
 if ( !dir1.IsOpened() )
    {
        // deal with the error here - wxDir would already log an error message
        // explaining the exact reason of the failure
        return;
    }
    puts("Enumerating object files in current directory:");

  wxString path, filename, dirstring,filename1, dirstring1, img,imgPath,path1,img1,imgPath1;
    int i=0;
path=wxT("C:\\testing\\splitterwindow\\set\\devices");
    path1=wxT("C:\\testing\\splitterwindow\\set\\actions");
    img=wxT("C:\\testing\\splitterwindow\\set\\devices\\");
    img1=wxT("C:\\testing\\splitterwindow\\set\\actions\\");


   bool cont=dir.Open(path);
   bool cont1=dir1.Open(path1);
   cont = dir.GetFirst(&filename, wxEmptyString, wxDIR_DEFAULT);
    dirstring.Append(filename.c_str());
    cont1 = dir1.GetFirst(&filename1, wxEmptyString, wxDIR_DEFAULT);
    dirstring1.Append(filename1.c_str());
    while ( cont )
    {

        imgPath.clear();

        cont = dir.GetNext(&filename);


       dirstring.Append(filename.c_str());

       // Consturct the imagepath
       imgPath.Append(img.c_str());
       imgPath.Append(filename.c_str());



       //Now, add the images to the imagelist
       il->Add(wxBitmap(wxImage(imgPath.c_str())));
       i++;

    }

    while ( cont1 )
    {

        imgPath1.clear();
       cont1 = dir1.GetNext(&filename1);
dirstring1.Append(filename1.c_str());
       // Consturct the imagepath
       imgPath1.Append(img1.c_str());
       imgPath1.Append(filename1.c_str());

       //Now, add the images to the imagelist
       i2->Add(wxBitmap(wxImage(imgPath1.c_str())));
       i++;

    }
    //assigning the imagelist to listctrl
       ListCtrl1->AssignImageList(il, wxIMAGE_LIST_SMALL);
ListCtrl3->AssignImageList(i2, wxIMAGE_LIST_SMALL);

    for(int j=0;j < il->GetImageCount()-1;j++)
    {
        wxListItem itemCol;
        itemCol.SetId(j);
        itemCol.SetImage(j);
        itemCol.SetAlign(wxLIST_FORMAT_LEFT);
        ListCtrl1->InsertItem(itemCol);

    }
     for(int k=0;k < i2->GetImageCount()-1;k++)
    {
        wxListItem itemCol1;
        itemCol1.SetId(k);
        itemCol1.SetImage(k);
        itemCol1.SetAlign(wxLIST_FORMAT_LEFT);
        ListCtrl3->InsertItem(itemCol1);

    }
```

`